# spring security oauth2 multiple login no authentication object exception

Tags: spring, security, authentication, oauth-2.0

i have an application with spring security oauth2. i have one jdbc login working, and i want to add another authentication manager mapped with another login url. first login works, i can get token but, the second one give this error, how can i handle this? thanks...

```
<UnauthorizedException>
<error>unauthorized</error>
<error_description>An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext</error_description>
```

here is my security xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">

<!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" 
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <!-- <custom-filter ref="corsFilter" before="HEADERS_FILTER"/> -->
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/oauth/token2" create-session="stateless" 
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager2"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token2" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <!-- <custom-filter ref="corsFilter" before="HEADERS_FILTER"/> -->
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/restful/**" create-session="always"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/restful/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <custom-filter ref="corsFilter" before="HEADERS_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="corsFilter" class="com.monimetric.security.JCLCORSFilter" />

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>




<sec:ldap-server id="ldapServer"
    url="ldap://185.4.210.3:3268/dc=metric,dc=local" root="ou=Users,ou=Metric,dc=metric,dc=local"
    manager-dn="cn=metricappsuser,ou=Users,ou=Metric,dc=metric,dc=local"
    manager-password="fdGas5hja" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    erase-credentials="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

    <security:authentication-provider>
        <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="metricAppsDS"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, active, lastLoginTime FROM metricapps.tuser WHERE username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT tuser.username, trole.name FROM tuser, trole, tuserrole WHERE tuser.username = tuserrole.username and trole.id = tuserrole.roleId and tuser.username=?" />
        <security:password-encoder ref="base64PasswordEncoder" />

    <ldap-authentication-provider  user-search-base="ou=Metric" user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}"
        server-ref="ldapServer" user-context-mapper-ref="customLdapContextMapper"/>
</security:authentication-manager>


<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager2" id="authenticationManager2"
    erase-credentials="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service> 
            <sec:user name="asd" password="asd" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customLdapContextMapper" class="com.monimetric.ldap.mapper.CustomLdapContextMapper"></bean>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="metricAppsDS" />

</bean>


<!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
    and other things -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="12000" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="oauthRequestFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthRequestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="restapp" scope="read,write,trust" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">

    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

what i want is there will be two different url and each of them will have different login system, one of them will be JDBC and the other will be LDAP or something like that...

Comment: That's too much code to narrow down what is the exact problem, but I can tell you that you are not giving Spring-Security the User object which is to be populated in SecurityContextHolder. Now, what did you try to do and you got this error, also why is your AuthenticationManager commented out?

Comment: what i want is there will be two different url and each of them will have different login system, one of them will be JDBC and the other will be LDAP or something like that...

Comment: No experience with LDAP, but I would suggest first get your JDBC authentication running, that I can help you with. Remove the unecessary LDAP code for now, take a backup, focus on JDBC first. And you still didnt tell me why is your authentication manager commented out.

Comment: i removed comments, it was for test. JDBC part is already working. when i write second authenticationManager for LDAP or something else, token request return unauthorize error, written above....thats the problem

Comment: no, i couldnt make this work this way. instead, i created another app for ldap authentication. i have a seperate application just for ldap login. if i have to another login mechanism later, i will create one more app for that. this will work this way untill i found a clear solution. i guess spring security doesnt have a good clear solution for that.